# Using lambda function to sort dictionary list

Tags: list, function, dictionary, lambda

A dictionary contains name and age of a person. Use lambda function to filter out dictionaries for age less than 30 and then print the names of person in sorted list with name capitalized and prefixed with Mr or Ms depending on gender?

I am not able to sort the list with prefixed Mr or Ms depending on the gender with name capitalized.